# vba: copy sheet contents (not sheet)

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a copy of a sheet from a different Workbook
First I open the Workbook

```
' Open Workbook in background
Dim wbImport As Workbook
Set wbImport = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strFile, UpdateLinks:=True, ReadOnly:=True)
wbImport.Windows(1).Visible = True ' set to false
```

Then I try to copy it. The current code is based on the macro recorder. I also like to get hints how to improve this code

```
' Copy first sheet in Import Workbook
With wbImport.Sheets(1)
    .Range("A1").Select
    .Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    .Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
End With
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(outsheet).Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

The problem is, that the select function fails with error 1004.
What is wrong?

Comment: The clue is to set references to workbook objects, sheets and ranges so you won't have to `.Select`, `.Activate`, `.Copy` nor `.Paste` them. A very good starting point for you would be to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/9758194) post and it's answers.

Comment: Use "Option Explicit" in all your vba coding! Which "Select" does actually fail? Is the variable 'outsheet' defined?

Comment: See 5 copy alternatives: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54473767/how-to-fix-graphs-not-copying-over-to-new-sheet-with-pastespecial/54477636#54477636]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```vb
wbImport.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy
'Hard Copy the values like this:
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(outsheet).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(outsheet).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
```